# Refrigerator and wall socket next to it went out at same time

Tags: electrical

Last night I made coffee in a coffee maker plugged into a wall socket next to the refrigerator (the fridge has it's own circuit). The coffee was made but later that evening I found both appliances off. I checked the circuit breaker box and no circuits were off but I did an off/on for the fridge circuit and the wall circuit but no change. The fridge is 20+ years old but was doing fine. None of the nearby GFCI circuits have tripped. Does both going out at the same time indicate any particular problem?

Comment: This has happened to me, and the cause of it was a GFCI upstream that I didn’t know was wired in parallel [nor did the location of it make sense]. Was my first guess when I read your post, but then you said you already checked adjacent GFCIs. Very strange - interested to hear what you end up discovering.

Comment: Do the circuits share anything at all (cables, boxes, etc), or do they have their own separate home run cables back to the panel?

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all failures of this sort are a connection failure in an outlet box at or upstream from the failed outlet. As stated many times here, back stab outlets are notorious for eventually failing.   Cable failures inside wall are extremely rare but can be caused by rodent damage or physical damage like drilling to a cable to hang something on the wall!

Best approach is to determine which circuit the failed outlets are on, turn off the breaker and start pulling outlets and examine them.  While doing that, if they are back-stabs, it's a good idea to either reattach the wires using the screws or if old, just replace them with a good quality outlet (not the 79 cent specials)!